# Redirect to parent folder on .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, laravel-5

My Htdocs list folder

1. sofia (Laravel 5.2)
2. test1 (Laravel 5.2)
3. test2 (Laravel 5.2)

My URL Project is

```
https://localhost/sofia/public/login
```

how to edit my `.htaccess`

when type on my url

```
https://localhost
```

automatic redirect to `https://localhost/login` or `https://localhost/sofia/public/login`